# Множественное удаление выделенных элементов из TreeView

Tags: java, javafx

Моя задача сделать приложение с TreeView в который я могу добавить элементы и могу удалить. Но одно из условий сделать так, чтоб можно было удалить сразу несколько элементов. По одному выделенному элементу я могу удалить, но я не знаю как выделить и удалить сразу несколько. Вот код того что у меня уже получилось:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    TreeView<String> treeView;
    @FXML
    Button AddButton;
    @FXML
    Button DeleteButton;
    @FXML
    TextField element;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>();

        TreeItem<String> intel = new TreeItem<>("Intel");
        intel.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>("core i3"));
        intel.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>("core i5"));
        intel.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>("core i7"));

        TreeItem<String> amd = new TreeItem<>("AMD");
        amd.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>("FX-Series"));

        root.getChildren().add(intel);
        root.getChildren().add(amd);

        treeView.setRoot(root);
        treeView.setShowRoot(false);

        AddButton.setOnAction(event -> AddObject());
        DeleteButton.setOnAction(event -> RemoveObject());
    }
    public void AddObject() {
        TreeItem<String> selectedItem = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (!element.getText().equals("")) {
            selectedItem.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(element.getText()));
        }
    }
    public void RemoveObject() {
        TreeItem<String> selectedItems = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        selectedItems.getParent().getChildren().remove(selectedItems);
    }

}
```

Если нужен fxml файл, то вот:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="277.0" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Conroller.Controller">
    <children>
        <TreeView fx:id="treeView" layoutX="-1.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="300.0" />
        <Button fx:id="AddButton" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="209.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#AddObject" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="84.0" text="Добавить" />
        <TextField fx:id="element" layoutX="107.0" layoutY="210.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="178.0" />
        <Button fx:id="DeleteButton" layoutX="123.0" layoutY="250.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#RemoveObject" text="Изъять" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```